# This prolog program does not ask input from the user

Tags: prolog

This program when queried with patient(X) directly returns false

```
patient(X):-cancer(X);diabetes(X).

cancer(X):-pain(X).

diabetes(X):-sugar(X).

pain(X):-readPain(X)=='y'.
sugar(X):-readSugar(X)=='y'.


readPain(X):-write('is it painful?'),nl,read(X).
readSugar(X):-write('Do you have sugar problems?'),nl,read(X).
```

Comment: `readSugar(X) == 'y'`?

Comment: Prolog *predicates* are not *functions*. They do not return values the way you are using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write `readPain(X)=='y'.`. But Prolog interprets this as `(==)(readPain(X),'y')`. Prolog sees `readPain(X)` as a *term*, *not* as a predicate call.

In order to ask a if a person has `pain`, you should use:

```
pain :-
    readPain(y).
```

Now it will query the user, and if the user writes `y.`, the predicate will succeed. So can ask:

```
patient :- cancer; diabetes.

cancer :- pain.

diabetes :- sugar.

pain :-
    readPain(y).
sugar:-
    readSugar(y).

readPain(X) :-
    write('is it painful?'),nl,read(X).
readSugar(X) :-
    write('Do you have sugar problems?'),nl,read(X).
```

The `read/1` predicate queries the user for a *term*, parses that term, and will unify the parameter with that term. So that means that after you have called `readPain(X)`, `X` will have the value `y` in case the user has written `y.`. By performing unification with `y`, we check if that is indeed the case.